# Is there any reason not to empty my bank account?

Tags: earthbound

My dad keeps putting money in my bank account. Is there any reason not to take all of it out of the ATM at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If you are carrying money and lose to a monster, you lose about half of the money you are carrying. The money that is in your bank account however is safe. As long as you aren't going to be fighting, however, it is not a problem to take it out temporarily, since you can also put it back in.